# CSS provides dark-on-dark for visited links on Similar Questions sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's [a cool new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91568/feedback-requested-similar-questions-displayed-in-sidebar-on-ask) I just learned about while trying to write up a new Meta question. Now, I'm fond of dark backgrounds, but isn't dark text on dark background a bit on the Dark side of design practices?

[image: Dark on dark!]

This is also the case on the main Q&A, which took a while to test, but indeed, it also provides dark text for "visited" links, which means that they're very unreadable.

Comment: a fix is on the way.

Answer (score 1):

This has been completed now. ♪